# Think my ubuntu just broke, not sure how to fix it

Tags: boot, grub2, boot-repair

[image]

My laptop died on me and when I went to start it up, it wont boot ubuntu. I can get the menu in the picutre but if I click on ubuntu it just goes to like the background of ubuntu and gets stuck. Anyway I can fix it without going back to factory?

Comment: How did it "die"? Ran out of power?

Answer (score 0):

maybe something wrong with the hard drive? try booting from something else(bootable usb stick or liveCD CD) and check for the disk for "bad sectors"

To make a bootable usb stick:

1. Download UNetBootin and burn it into a usb stick. https://unetbootin.github.io/ (you can pick what flavor of Linux in the menu)

   - many tutorials online like this one: http://tecadmin.net/how-to-install-unetbootin-on-ubuntu-linuxmint/ (be careful and pick the correct drive)
2. Restart the computer and boot with the usb stick. (the order of boot can be set in the BIOS, usually by pressing the `del` key when it's booting up)
3. In the start up menu pick `Try Ubuntu without installing`
4. Once you're in Ubuntu, you can open the `disks`(Ubuntu 16.04) to check your hard drive and see if there are any "bad sectors".

Comment: While the hard drive could be a problem, you need to provide complete details on the process.  This is better suited as a comment.  Please try to answer questions with completeness until you have enough rep to comment.